# Incompatible output argument. [scilab]

Tags: scilab

I am trying to write a program in scilab to carry out a frequency analysis of the .WAV file using a common-or-garden FFT, and compare and contrast the response with that of a Welch periodogram for differing window functions.
But when I try running the program it gives me a `Incompatible output argument` error on line 35.

I thought it was because the numbers didn't line up but I did the math and everything should line up. If anyone has any ideas on why this error keeps popping up that would really helpful.

```
nsecs = 5;
Fs = 44100;
N = nsecs*Fs;

n = linspace (0, N-1, N)

f1 = 1440;
f2 = 1570;

y = 1.2*sin(2*%pi*f1*n/N).*cos (2*%pi*f2*n/N)
y = y + 0.2*rand(1, N)


M = 128
Nn = 13844
HnWin = window( 'hn', Nn )

times = 20
all = list()
xn = zeros( 1, Nn/2)
tmpp = 0

for i = 1:Nn
     tmp = y(1:Nn)
     ztmp = fft(tmp.*HnWin)/Nn
     all($+1) = ztmp
end

for i = 1:length(all)/(M-times)
    for j = 1:M
        if i==0 then
            tmpp = tmpp + all(j:M)
        else
            tmpp = tmpp + all(j+i+times:M)
        end
    end
    xn(i,:) = tmpp/M
    times = times + 1
end

for i = 1:length(xn)
    avg = avg + xn(i)
end

avg = avg/length(xn)
```

Answer (score 0):

all is a list so all(j+i+times:M) points to a set of elements which cannot be added to the scalar tmpp

Comment: I'm fairly new to scilabs, so what you just said didn't make any since to me. Do you have any suggestions for making it work.